# Making an online quiz game accessible for the blind and visually impaired

Tags: html, accessibility

I'm working on a game and I am also required to add extremely good support for screen readers and all other accessibility needs.

In the game, the user selects an answer and the website shows what is the correct answer in green color and the score updates on the top.

But for blind people, when they select an answer, they will not be able to know if it was correct, what is their final score (which is updated on the top of the page), or how many wrong answers they have had so far. Because the game ends in 3 strikes.

I can add success sounds or wrong answer sounds but this will not inform them about what was the right answer (which becomes green) or what is their score after answering that question. Is there any way I can send screen readers commands to read "Your answer X is correct, your score is 50" or "Your answer X is wrong, correct answer is Y, you have 2 strikes so far"?

I'm open to other solutions. What are the best practices for online games for accessibility?

Comment: [ARIA Live regions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Live_Regions) (<div role="log"></div>), may be

Comment: Can you explain in an answer how to use it

Comment: After an answer is marked as correct, does the user have to click something to get to the next question?

Comment: Use Has to click something, but I'm also interested in learning sending messages to screen readers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a `<div>` (or some kind of container) with the `aria-live='polite'` property.  Any time you update the text in that `<div>`, the screen reader will read the new text.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-live.

Your html should have something like this:

```
<div id='answer' aria-live='polite'></div>
```

and your javascript would have something like this:

```
<script>
  document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = 'Sorry, answer B is wrong.  The correct answer is C.'
</script>
```

(*Note, use innerHTML or innerText or whatever attribute is appropriate for setting the text to be displayed.*)

You can follow this same pattern for adding another message about how many answers are wrong so far (or include it in the same message above).

If you are indicating the right answer by changing the color to green, keep in mind that some color-deficient users cannot distinguish green from other colors.  In addition to changing the correct answer to green, you should also make it bold or italic, or have a "(correct answer)" tag in front of it, or some other indication in addition to the color.

Comment: Do div#answer must be visible to other users or can i make it display:none;?

Comment: The ‘div’ does not have to be visible but don’t hide it with display:none. Hide it by making it one pixel tall and pushing it offscreen. Do a google search for the “visually-hidden” class or “sr-only” class.